# Fail to get flash effect by given times when using animate package

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, animate

Text flash effect is the purpose of the following simple code. Some text should flash for a given times(here is nine times) by a `\foreach` loop command.
However, it can not pass compile.
This error message is always given:

```
Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width.
```

What's wrong with this code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,scale=1]{2} 
    flash something
    \foreach \x in {1,...,9}{% flash nine times
        \newframe 
            \newframe flash something
    }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of TikZ/PGF's `\foreach` is faulty.

Any of the LaTeX3 comma-list mapping commands, such as `\clist_map_inline:nn`, does a better job here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\clistMapInlinenn\clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{2} 
  \strut flash something: 0
  \clistMapInlinenn{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
    \newframe 
    \newframe\strut flash something: #1
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

---

Note that package `animate` provides its own loop command for multiplying animation frames:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}                                                                                                  
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{2}                                                                                
\multiframe{9}{i=0+1}{        % 2nd argument may be left empty,                                                   
  \strut flash something: \i  % if a loop variable is not needed                                                  
  \newframe % <--- This one creates the blank in-between frame.                                                   
}                                                                                                                 
\newframe                                                                                                         
\strut flash something: 9                                                                                         
\end{animateinline}                                                                                               

\end{document}
```

---

There is nothing wrong with using `\foreach` *inside* a frame definition. Just don't embed `\newframe` into the `\foreach` body. E. g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{2}
\multiframe{9}{i=0+1}{
  \strut flash something:\makebox[1.2in][l]{%
                           \foreach \x in {0,...,\i}{ \x}}
  \newframe
}
\newframe
\strut flash something:\makebox[1.2in][l]{%
                         \foreach \x in {0,...,9}{ \x}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does \foreach not work here?

Comment: Perhaps some deficiency of the `\foreach` implementation.